# How to save custom typed object, which contains an array of custom structs, to realm (in swift)?

Tags: swift, core-data, realm, persistence

I have a very similar question to [Saving an array of custom objects that each contain an array of custom objects, best method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538309/saving-an-array-of-custom-objects-that-each-contain-an-array-of-custom-objects), except I'm currently down the path of trying to use Realm to store my data instead of CoreData.  I'd like to know:

1. if there's a compelling reason I should consider reworking my code to implement CoreData instead of Realm
2. if Realm is still a good option, how do I properly implement my array of `IngredientObjects`, which is an array of custom structs inside my `RecipeObjet`.

The code builds, but when I add a new `Recipe` in my app and click save, it crashes with the error

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', 
reason: 'Property 'ingredients' is declared as 'NSArray', which is not a supported RLMObject property type"
```

Originally, I create a class `Recipe`, which contains an array of `Ingredient` structs.  Once I decided to go with Realm, created a `RecipeObject` Class and an `IngredientObject` class, which are *supposed* to be realm-storage-friendly data formats. I also created a `Persistable` protocol and made both the `Recipe` class and the `Ingrededient` struct extend `Persistable` in order to to have methods to essentially translate a `Recipe` into a `RecipeObject`, and an Ingredient into an IngredientObject.

Finally, my first storage method is an add method in my `RecipeStore` class; I have not implemented any fetching methods yet.

Code below:

```
//Recipe.swift
import UIKit
import os.log
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

public class Recipe: Persistable {

    //MARK: Properties
    dynamic var name: String
    dynamic var numServed: Float?
    dynamic var photo: UIImage?
    dynamic var rating: Int
    dynamic var ingredients: [Ingredient]
    var notes: String?


    //MARK: Initialization

    init?(name: String, numServed: Float?, ingredients: [Ingredient], photo: UIImage?, rating: Int, notes: String?) {

        // The name must not be empty
        guard !name.isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        // The rating must be between 0 and 5 inclusively
        guard (rating >= 0) && (rating <= 5) else {
            return nil
        }

        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name
        self.numServed = numServed
        self.photo = photo
        self.rating = rating
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.notes = notes
    }

    //Persistable required functions
    //Create a Recipe from a RecipeObj
    required public init(managedObject: RecipeObject) {
        name = managedObject.name ?? ""
        numServed = managedObject.numServed ?? 0.0
        photo = UIImage(data: managedObject.photo as! Data) ?? nil
        rating = managedObject.rating ?? 0
        ingredients = [Ingredient]()
        //ingredients = managedObject.ingredients.flatMap(Ingredient.init(managedObject:))
        let count = managedObject.ingredients?.count ?? 0
        if (count > 0) {
            for i in 0...count {
                ingredients[i].qty = managedObject.ingredients?[i].qty
                ingredients[i].uom = managedObject.ingredients?[i].uom
                ingredients[i].name = managedObject.ingredients?[i].name
            }
        }
        notes = managedObject.notes ?? ""
    }

    //Create a RecipeObject from a Recipe
    public func managedObject() -> RecipeObject {
        let objName = name ?? ""
        let objNumServed: Float = numServed ?? 0.0
        let objPhoto = photo
        let objRating = rating ?? 0
        var objIngredients = [IngredientObject]()
        for i in 0...ingredients.count {
            objIngredients[i] = ingredients[i].managedObject()
        }
        let objNotes = notes ?? ""
        let recipeObject = RecipeObject(name: objName, numServed: objNumServed, photo: objPhoto!, rating: objRating, ingredients: objIngredients, notes: objNotes ?? "")
        return recipeObject
    }
}

____________________
//Ingredient.swift
import Foundation

public struct Ingredient {
    //Properties
    public var qty: Float?
    public var uom: String?
    public var name: String?
}

_______________________
//RecipeObject.swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final public class RecipeObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var numServed: Float = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var photo: NSData? = nil
    @objc dynamic var rating: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var ingredients: [IngredientObject]? = nil
    @objc dynamic var notes: String? = ""
    //dynamic var recipeID = UUID().uuidString


    convenience init(name: String, numServed: Float, photo: UIImage, rating: Int, ingredients: [IngredientObject]?, notes: String) {
        //debug
        print ("REcipeObject required init")
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.numServed = numServed
        if let data = photo.pngData() {
            self.photo = data as NSData
        } else if let data = photo.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.0) {
            self.photo = data as NSData
         } else {
            self.photo = nil
        }

        self.rating = rating
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.notes = notes
    }

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
}


_____________________
//IngredientObject.swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final public class IngredientObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var qty: Float = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var uom = ""
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    //@objc dynamic var ingredientID = UUID().uuidString

   override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
}

_______________________
//IngredientPersistable.swift
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

extension Ingredient: Persistable {

    //assign struct values FROM an IngredientObject
    public init(managedObject: IngredientObject) {
        qty = managedObject.qty
        uom = managedObject.uom
        name = managedObject.name
    }

    //assign struct values TO an ingredient object
    public func managedObject() -> IngredientObject {
        let ingredient = IngredientObject()
        ingredient.qty = qty ?? 0.0
        ingredient.uom = uom ?? ""
        ingredient.name = name ?? ""
        return ingredient
    }
}

_______________
//Persistable.swift

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

/// Represents a type that can be persisted using Realm.
public protocol Persistable {

    associatedtype ManagedObject: Object
    //associatedtype PropertyValue: PropertyValueType = DefaultPropertyValue
    //associatedtype Query: QueryType = DefaultQuery

    init(managedObject: ManagedObject)

    func managedObject() -> ManagedObject
}

_________________
//RecipeStore.swift

import UIKit
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

enum RuntimeError: Error {
    case NoRealmSet
}
class RecipeStore {
var realm: Realm?

    public func addRecipe(_ recipe: Recipe) throws
    {
        if (realm != nil) {
            var newRecipeObject: RecipeObject
            newRecipeObject = recipe.managedObject()
            try! realm?.write {
                realm?.add(newRecipeObject)
            }
        } else {
            throw RuntimeError.NoRealmSet
        }
    }
```

Comment: Three things. 1) Opinion type questions are OT for SO, please avoid those. 2) There's way to much code in your question - take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 3) Realm does't have arrays. Simply change your Ingredients Struct to a realm object, then in your Recipe class add this `let ingredientList = List<Ingredients>()`. Let me know if you need further clarification. See [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Jay, your answer was simple and worked :). Also, thanks for pointing out the mistakes in my question, will better observe those guidelines going forward.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm taking a look at this question and have some feedback for the contributors. First, there are 2 different questions in the OP. Second the answer to _one_ of them is in a comment and there is no accepted answer, even though the OP has seemed to accept by the comment above. I'm not trying to be critical, just to understand the platform better, help if able, and save some time.